# Excel/VBA Filling a variable with current column-name

Tags: excel, variables, vba

I am using Excel and creating a macro.

My macro so far finds the next empty column and stops there to fill stuff in.
Then it creates a new sheet, referencing to the first sheet. Because I could get the Column-Number (Selection.Column) I could actually do what I wanted, but I had to use several if-clauses.

But if I could just get the Column-name (A, B, C, D, etc...), I could store it in a variable before I create the new sheet in the macro and then my references would be much easier.

Just in case I couldn't get my question across (English is my 4th language):
If the cell B3 was selected, I want to store "B" in a variable.

```
Dim ColumnName As String
ColumnName = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```
ColumnName = Split(ActiveCell.Address(1, 1), "$")(1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply! Worked as I wanted it to work!